# Send tree from a directory via SMTP through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, smtp

I'm trying to develop a small script that sends the output of a tree of a certain directory, and I'm having problems with the presentation of the mail; The script already sends the info, but not in the way that I would like. My code is as follows:

```
# from to info
$MailFrom = ""
$MailTo = ""

# Credentials
$Username = "user"
$Password = "password"

# Server Info
$SmtpServer = "server"
$SmtpPort = "port"

# Menssage
$MessageSubject = "test" 
$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $MailFrom,$MailTo
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $false
$Message.Subject = $MessageSubject
$Message.Body = tree /F directoryroute

# SMTP Client object
$Smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer,$SmtpPort)
$Smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$Smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password)
$Smtp.Send($Message)
```

So, the thing is that the mail shows the info like this:
[image: picture 1]

When in fact, I want to see the following:
[image: Picture 2]

I am using power shell ISE and the tree is also different there:
[image: Picture 3]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the [`.BodyEncoding` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding) to a character encoding that can represent the box-drawing characters that the `tree.com` utility uses for visualization, preferably UTF-8:

```bash
$Message.BodyEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

Additionally, since the [`.Body` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding) is a *single string* (`[string]`), whereas the lines output by `tree.com` are captured in an *array* by PowerShell, you need to create a multi-line string representation yourself:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
$Message.Body = tree /F directoryroute | Out-String
```

If you neglect to do that, PowerShell implicitly stringifies the array, which means joining the array elements on a *single* line with *spaces*, which results in what you saw.

---

As for the PowerShell ISE:

It *misinterprets* output from external programs such as `tree.com`, because it uses the system's *ANSI* code page by default for decoding, whereas most external programs use the *OEM* code page.

The ISE has other limitations, summarized in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375), is [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and notably cannot run the modern, cross-platform PowerShell edition, [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).

Consider migrating to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), which is an actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience.

In case you do want to make `tree.com` work in the ISE, run the following:

```bash
[Console]::OutputEncoding =
  Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
```

---

<sup>[1] While using [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) is convenient, it always appends a *trailing newline* to its output - see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444). If you need to avoid that, use `(tree /F directoryroute) -join [Environment]::NewLine` instead.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved the interpretation issues and the characters are shown as they should. Unfortunately they are put consecutively instead of being in actual tree form. How can that be solved?

Thanks in advance, this has been very helpful so far

Comment: That can be solved by piping the output of the `tree` command to `out-string`: `$Message.Body = tree /F directoryroute | Out-String`.

Comment: KeithMiller is correct, @shagraath_ - please see my update, which also explains why this is necessary.

Comment: Nice, now all is solved and the script is working as intended, thank you very much guys!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @shagraath_; my pleasure.